# Error Unkown Property payfor

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm having a page(say VF1) and in another page(VF2) I'm getting all the values of page1.Here my problem is in my page1 Im having repeated values and need to save them

In my VF1

```
 <apex:dataTable value="{!items}" var="item" style="margin-left:60px;" >
                     <apex:column headervalue="Payment For"></apex:column >
                     {!item.iTemname}          
                     <apex:column headervalue="Unit Price"></apex:column >
                     {!item.unitprice}
                </apex:dataTable>
```

and class

```
public list<string> items{get;set;}
public string itemlist{get;set;}
items.add(itemlist);
```

I have written it in second page as

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!items}" var="item" style="margin-left:60px;" >
                 <apex:column headervalue="Payment For"></apex:column >
                 {!item.payfor}          
                 <apex:column headervalue="Unit Price"></apex:column >
                 {!item.price}
            </apex:dataTable>
```

and in my constructor

```
  tempinvoiceid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('tempinvoiceid');
List<object__c> tempin =[select item_name__c,price__c from object__c where id=:tempinvoiceid];
 for(integer i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            payfor = tempin[i].Item_Name__c;
            price = tempin[i].price__c;
        }
```

then getting error as Unknown property 'string.payfor'
How should I display in my Page2....Any Help!!!!

Comment: Not sure what you want. But I guess you are Listing all the items in first page and when user is clicking the same you are redirecting the user to a second page. This is what you want?

Comment: yes absolutely right.....I'm having two objects object1__c & object2__c with lookup relationship and i'll be inserting values in page1.now need to get the values in page2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!items}" var="item" style="margin-left:60px;" >
             <apex:column headervalue="Payment For"></apex:column >
             {!tempin.Item_Name__c}          
             <apex:column headervalue="Unit Price"></apex:column >
             {!tempin.price__c}
        </apex:dataTable>
```

In the controller make a getter and setter of the List of object you want to show data of .

Comment: if you don't mind can u tell me how can I get the values from page1 to page2 of itemname and Unitprice

Comment: You can use components to get that

Comment: <apex:component> tag